# Why does my Query take so long to produce result

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have the following query that takes about 20-30 seconds to produce a result. I would like to get the result time down, I am using access on the front end to create queries and SQL Server on the backend. Not sure if there is an easier way and quicker way to run this query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [UB-04s].client_id, 
    DATEDIFF("yyyy", [UB-04s]![patient_dob], [UB-04s]![admit_date]) AS [AGE at Admission], 
    invalid_diag_codes_by_age.start_age_yrs, 
    invalid_diag_codes_by_age.end_age_yrs, 
    invalid_diag_codes_by_age.diag_code 
INTO 
    tmp10407
FROM 
    [UB-04s], invalid_diag_codes_by_age
WHERE 
    ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
    AND (([UB-04s].dx_Q)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
    AND (([UB-04s].dx_P)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_O)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_N)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_M)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_L)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_K)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_J)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_I)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_H)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_G)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_F)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_E)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_D)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_C)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_B)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].dx_A)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code])) OR ((([UB-04s].client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
   AND (([UB-04s].principal_dx)=[invalid_diag_codes_by_age].[diag_code]));
```

THESE ARE JUST SNIPPETS FROM THE TABLES AS THESE ARE LARGE TABLES...

FIELDS FROM TABLE UB04s:

```
client_id   principal_dx    dx_A    dx_B    dx_C    dx_D    dx_E    dx_F    dx_G    dx_H    dx_I    dx_J    dx_K    dx_L    dx_M    dx_N    dx_O    dx_P    dx_Q
527                                                                     
530     42843   4280    4148    41519   42741   4271    5849    5770    5739        99702   431 2760    44422   28981   28984   2384    78551   42611
531     5715    44489   34839   0785    99682   4589    5723    2762    42518       99779   99811   5180    2689    2769    57142   5680    4471    2894
533     5559    V145                                                                
116     2761    7802    4019    2724    V1582   2768                                                
117     55321
```

FIELDS FROM     INVALID DIAG CODES TABLE:

```
diag_code   start_age_yrs   end_age_yrs age_range_desc  
04041           0               0.5         0-6 months of age       
27701           0                1          
3070           18                99         
99779           0                1          
5559           15                99
```

Basically what I am doing is searching through all diag codes for a client to see if it is a invalid diag code based on the clients age.

Comment: You have a cross join in there because you used a comma separated list of tables and didn't include the join predicates in the where clause. This is a bad way to write queries. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Also, it seems you have some serious normalization issues here. You seem to have repeating groups which violates 1NF and causes untold amounts of pain. Last but not least, that DATEDIFF function is NOT valid sql server syntax.

Comment: Without knowing what the tables look like and what you're trying to accomplish, it would be difficult to try to rewrite this for you.  But I have to say that it certainly appears to be very poorly written.  I'm imagining you could use an inner join instead of a cross join, and an 'WHERE x IN ()' clause instead of your huge list of contingencies.

Comment: I cannot use a join, as this would produce unwanted results. Clients have multiple diag codes that have to be stored in separate fields, that are then compared to another table that lists all diag codes in one column. The problem if I insert a join it gives me unnecessary diag codes that are not tied to the client.

Comment: You are using a join here....it is a cross join. This is most likely why you are getting unwanted results. Your where predicates are a complete mess. It looks like they were written by the automated tool in Access. You need to clean that up so you can read it. You seem to have a number of logical challenges in there.

Comment: @SikRikDaRula Well, using `[UB-04s], invalid_diag_codes_by_age` is going to make it exponentially slower over time.  There's no way to help you without descriptions of table structures and 'desired result'.

Comment: @SEan LAnge , I am getting the correct results with the cross join, but as soon as I use an inner join I get mulitiple rows produced with invalid diag codes that the client didnt even have. I will try to update my question with the table structures

Comment: re: *"I am using access on the front end to create queries and SQL Server on the backend."* - Just to clarify, you are using a normal *Select Query* in Access against ODBC Linked Tables that reside on a SQL Server (as opposed to a *Pass-Through Query*). Is that correct?

Comment: @Gord Thompson That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no real details to work with and I am totally guessing as to what you want. But using aliases and removing all the extra parenthesis will help considerably. I also used IN instead of the repeated predicates. This is not going to work exactly like this but is pretty close.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.client_id
    , DateDiff(year, [UB-04s]![patient_dob], [UB-04s]![admit_date]) AS [AGE at Admission]
    , i.start_age_yrs
    , i.end_age_yrs
    , i.diag_code 
INTO tmp10407
FROM [UB-04s] u
cross join invalid_diag_codes_by_age i
WHERE u.client_id = [Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id] 
AND 
(
    u.dx_Q = i.diag_code
) 
OR 
(
    u.principal_dx = i.diag_code
    AND
    i.diag_code in 
    (
        u.dx_P
        , u.dx_O
        , u.dx_N
        , u.dx_M
        , u.dx_L
        , u.dx_K
        , u.dx_J
        , u.dx_I
        , u.dx_H
        , u.dx_G
        , u.dx_F
        , u.dx_E
        , u.dx_D
        , u.dx_C
        , u.dx_B
        , u.dx_A
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sean Lange, your answer got me what I needed with some tweaking. here is my final query that is returned within 3-5secs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.client_id, DateDiff("yyyy",u.patient_dob,u.admit_date) AS [AGE at Admission], i.start_age_yrs, i.end_age_yrs, i.diag_code INTO tmp10407
FROM [UB-04s] AS u, invalid_diag_codes_by_age AS i
WHERE (((u.client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
AND ((i.diag_code) In ([u].[dx_P],[u].[dx_O],[u].[dx_N],[u].[dx_M],[u].[dx_L],[u].[dx_K],[u].[dx_J],[u].[dx_I],[u].[dx_H],[u].[dx_G],[u].[dx_F],[u].[dx_E],[u].[dx_D],[u].[dx_C],[u].[dx_B],[u].[dx_A]))) 
OR (((u.client_id)=[Forms]![frmUB04s]![client_id]) 
AND ((u.principal_dx) In ([i].[diag_code])));
```